# Windows Authentication-enabled IIS Site performs differently with 2 different bindings

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a site set up in IIS 7, and it is using Windows Authentication as the only enabled Authentication Mode. It utilizes a custom .NET 4 Application Pool - the pool uses the default ApplicationPoolIdentity. This site is a C#/ASP.NET application with its own page authorization rules (generated using Iron Speed Designer 9). I have the two bindings set up below:

servicedirectory.sampledomain.com

booking.sampledomain.com

Both of these bindings are mapped to the site on all available IPs on port 80.

For the most part, browsing through either binding works successfully, except for a certain page where I create a WebRequest that fetches another page as a Stream. (I am taking the other page's contents and embedding them as an attachment in an iCal (.ics) file for inclusion in meeting requests. The file is downloaded and sent out by the user)

```
String request = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path).
    Replace("Conference.aspx", "Confirmation.aspx") +
    "?Conference=" + conference.ConferenceId;
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(request);
webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
// Send the data.
newStream.Close();
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(ms);
    attachmentContent = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

responseStream.Close();
```

The problem is the following: this code succeeds and produces the content from the Confirmation.aspx page as String data (attachmentContent variable) when the user is browsing under the first binding (servicedirectory.sampledomain.com). However, I get a 401.1 error at the `WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();` line when browsing via the other binding URL. There are *no* references in the application source code or web.config to either binding - everything was built with the intention of being deployed to any URL.

Why would two different bindings affect this?